# Dart: Class inheritance member repetition

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart, if I have a class that extends another, is there a simple way to extend all of the members without repeating them all in extending class?

```
class Foo {
  String id;

  Foo({
    @required this.id,
  });
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  String id;
  String name;

  Bar({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
  }) : super(
    id: id,
  );
}
```

This code works fine, however, as the members of `Foo` increase, it becomes very cumbersome to have to repeat the properties of `Foo` inside of `Bar`. Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are not repeating it. but overriding them in your `Bar` class.

You can simply do

```
class Foo {
  String id;

  Foo({
    @required this.id,
  });
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  String name;

  Bar({
    @required String id,
    @required this.name,
  }) : super(
          id: id,
        );
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok so that's not too bad. Coming from Java/JavaScript so trying to get my head around the constructor syntax ha.